# Lua: `.-` pattern matching with optional end character

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match the first part of a path, for example the 'a' in the following strings:

```
/a/b/c
/a/b
/a/
/a
```

The pattern `"^/(.-)/"` works in all cases except the last one, and when I intruduce a `?` to make the final slash optional, it stops working at all, why's that?

```
> = string.match("/a/", "^/(.-)/")
a
> = string.match("/a", "^/(.-)/")
nil
> = string.match("/a", "^/(.-)/?")

>
```

Comment: It does not stop working.  It successfully found correct match with empty string.  Try `^/([^/]*)`

Comment: Thanks, that works. Totally didn't realize the missing `nil` meant something.